# How to join on navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity Contractors that has a navigation property ContractorDistributorCnIds. I have also another entity (table) Distributors. I need to join ContractorDistributorCnIds to Distributors on DistNo field. I cannot use navigation here, as Distributors table is in another database, so I use join. Here is what I tried:

```
            result = (from c in contractors
                  .Include(c => c.ContractorDistributorCnIds)
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .ToList()
                  join d in _anotherDbContext.Distributors on c.ContractorDistributorCnIds.DistNo equals d.CustNo
                  select ...;
```

This does not work, as I get an error: "'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'DistNo'".

How can this be fixed?

### Edited

Here are simplified models for Contractors and ContractorDistributorCnIds:

```
public partial class Contractors
{
    public Contractors()
    {
        ContractorDistributorCnIds = new HashSet<ContractorDistributorCnIds>();
    }

    public int ContractorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContractorDistributorCnIds> ContractorDistributorCnIds { get; set; }
}

public partial class ContractorDistributorCnIds
{
    public int ContractorId { get; set; }
    public int DistNo { get; set; }

    public virtual Contractors Contractor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your models? At least the definition for `contractors` and `ContractorDistributorCnIds`?

Comment: @kalexi I added them to my question.

Comment: Make ICollection IEnumerable, IQueryable or List

Comment: @user10728126 I am not sure about it. The models are generated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to join by a collection property. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and what result set you're trying to materialize, but you could at least give this a shot:

```cs
// loading contractors
var contractors = contractorsDbSet
    .Include(c => c.ContractorDistributorCnIds)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();

// loading distributors
var distNos = contractors
    .SelectMany(x => x.ContractorDistributorCnIds)
    .Select(x => x.DistNo)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
var distributors = distributorsDbSet.Where(x => distNos.Contains(x.DistNo)).ToList();
```

This way you load contractors, and then distributors are loaded by DistNo's found inside `contractors`. From here you can proceed to join them as you like.

You would then unite them into a list of view models with code similar to this:

```cs
var viewModels = contractors.Select(contractor =>
{
    var distNos = contractor.ContractorDistributorCnIds.Select(x => x.DistNo).ToArray();
    var distributorsFromSecondDb = distributors.Where(y => distNos.Contains(y.DistNo)).ToArray();
    var contractorDistributors = contractor.ContractorDistributorCnIds.Join(
        distributorsFromSecondDb,
        x => x.DistNo,
        x => x.DistNo,
        (fromSecondDb, fromFirstDb) => new
        {
            fromSecondDb,
            fromFirstDb
        });
    return new ContractViewModel(contractor, contractorDistributors);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let me still explain what I wanted to achieve. The query I am trying to write will be used to populate a List of ContractorViewModels, each of which has a list of Distributors. So Contractors to ContractorDistributorCnIds is one-to-many, and ContractorDistributorCnIds to Distributors is one-to-one. The Distributors table is needed just to get some additional info not present in ContractorDistributorCnIds. I wonder if this can be achieved in one query...

Comment: So, you need to get contractors from first database, get related distributors from second database, and then join them together to form a view model?
If the data is in the different databases, there is no way you'll be sending a single DB query.

Comment: Contractors and ContractorDistributorCnIds are in the same database, but Distributors are in the other database. If I did not need some distributors details missing in ContractorDistributorCnIds, I could easily use navigation (as I do), but unfortunately those details are in the Distributors table which is in another database.

Comment: Well, looks like you must query two databases, so you'll be sending two database queries anyway. If you wonder if the code can be condensed into a single query, then I say it's not worth it. Among other things, it might confuse the reader into thinking that this code only does a single DB request. Also, putting too much stuff into IQueryable chain can cause EF to evaluate in-memory, not in-database - you don't want that. At least in my answer, only needed Distributors are ever loaded from the second DB. I've updated my answer with some sample code to build view-models from the results.

Comment: I see. Let me think a little on how I can apply it. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use Include() instead of SelectMany()? If no, maybe join?

Comment: I'm only talking about code you've shared, since I have no knowledge about your real code. It's not possible to `Include()` instead of `SelectMany()` because `contractors` are already loaded from the DB, and `Include()` is Entity Framework feature that extends `IQueryable`. Since we've already loaded contractors, we don't query anymore.
Can you describe what kind of data you would like to have? Can you in any way apply last code snippet in the answer? I'm joining distributors from two databases into `contractorDistributors` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198895/discussion-between-david-shochet-and-kalexi).